# List<T> and List<V> map to a new Map<T,T>

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

if I have two list.

the first is List:

```
[
{
  "A":"code1"
  "B":"1"
},
{
  "A":"code2"
  "B":"1,2"
},
{
  "A":"code3"
  "B":"2,3"
}
]
```

and the second is List:

```
[
{
  "C":"target1"
  "D":"1"
},
{
  "C":"target2"
  "D":"2"
},
{
  "C":"target3"
  "D":"3"
}
]
```

now I need a new Map

```
"code1" = "target1","code2" = "target1,target2","code3" = "target2,target3"
```

the rule is when the

```
List<Object1>.getB().contains(List<Object2>.getD())
```

I map it to a new Map,replace C to B.

I can use double for to make it.

eg:

```
public void dosome(){
        Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(Object1 object1 : object1s){
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Object2 object2 : object2s){
                if(object1.getB().contains(object2.getD())){
                    list.add(object2.getC());
                }
            }
            map.put(object1.getA(),list);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

But I want to change using double "for" circle to using stream()(java8) to make my code more beautiful!

Comment: Please share your attempts with community. Show your code. What did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: I add it in my question.I want change "for" to stream() to make my code beautiful

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeking a functional solution, here's one way of doing this in functional style:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map =
        object1s.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Object1::getA,
                               o1 -> object2s.stream()
                                             .filter(o2 -> o1.getB().contains(o2.getD()))
                                             .map(Object2::getC)
                                             .collect(toList()),
                               (a, b) -> b));
```